# Calculating VAT backwards always returns as 0 in c#

Tags: c#, double

```
public string s()
{ 
  double price = 123.12
  double preVatPrice = (100 / (100 + 20) + price);

  return preVatPrice.ToString();
}
```

in c# this always returns as '0' any ideas why?

Comment: Have you tried forcing floating point arithmatic using `(100d / (100+20))` instead?

Comment: Isn't there a faq for this thing ? And also, don't use `double` for prices.

Comment: Your formula is incorrect, even after fixing the integer division. Should be something like this, imo: `decimal price = 123.12m; decimal preVatPrice = price / 1.2m;`

Comment: yes the probably is an FAQ for working out vat backwards but i know how to do it already just the c# issue with doubles i wasnt aware of.

Answer (score 8):

This is [integer division](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegerDivision.html):

```
100 / (100 + 20)
```

That will result in a 0.

Make it into:

```
100.0 / (100.0 + 20.0)
```

To ensure all parameters are floating point types.

---

BTW - the function returns "123.12" when I test it.

---

Update:

As pointed out in several comments - you should be using [`decimal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.aspx) for monetary calculations, though in this case it is unlikely to be a problem.

> The Decimal value type is appropriate for financial calculations requiring large numbers of significant integral and fractional digits and no round-off errors.

Comment: You might want to use decimal when working with money, though. JUst as a general rule; it probably doesn't make any difference in this case.

Comment: It might; round-off errors like trailing 000000...1's happen when you least expect them, and at least from a high level they can appear random. If you can't tolerate them (money), use decimal. if you can (most 3D math), float or double is OK.

Answer (score 1):

Some of your literals are ints, use `(100.0 / (100.0 + 20.0) + price)` to get double precision arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

```
double preVatPrice = ((double)100 / (100 + 20) + price);
```